# Getting Column Index from SSDBGrid in VB6

Tags: datagrid, crystal-reports, vb6, iteration, infragistics

I'm producing a report in Crystal Reports where the column order must match the order that they're displayed in in the `SSDBGrid` in `VB6`.

To do this, I decided it was best to loop over each column in the grid, and call a function to set the parameter field values to the correct heading (so, column 0's caption would be the value for parameter field @Col1, etc)

Anyway, the code I have for this is

```
Dim c As Column
Dim cName As String

For Each c In FShow_All_Accounts.grd_accounts.Columns
   cName = "@Col" & c.ListIndex
   Call setColumnHeaders(c.Index)
   crxReport.ParameterFields.GetItemByName(cName).AddCurrentValue ("f")
Next
```

The problem is that first of all, setting the type of `c` to Column and looping over each `c` in grd_accounts seems to be incorrect - grd_accounts is an `SSDBGrid`, and secondly, it errors when trying to return the index.

So, my question(s):

- What is the correct way to loop over each column in an `SSDBGrid`?
- Secondly, how would I then get the column index for the correct column, to pass into the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is actually more simple than you're imagining it to be. Your code is *very* nearly there.

```
Dim c As Column
Dim i As String
Dim cname As String

i = 0

For Each c in grd_accounts.Columns
  i = i + 1
  cName = "@Col" & i
  crxReport.ParameterFields.GetItemByName(cName).AddCurrentValue (c.Caption)
Next
```

No need for the helper function. This will iterate over each column, set cName to be "@Col" and the value of i (Also the column number), and therefore that parameter field in the report will be captioned with that columns caption.

Comment: This nearly works, except that when I change the order of the columns, it still prints the columns in the same order?

Comment: Don't worry, I've just kept it as it is for now, with the columns in a fixed order.